# Publishing GeoTIFF using WCS service with QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis-server, wcs

I need to publish some GeoTIFFs using QGIS Server (2.2.0-1+precise1).  I already have installed and setup QGIS Server to serve those geotiffs via WMS.  But I need to serve rather the raster data to be able to use it in raster calculations.

I don't know how to set up or call the service from an URL.  I tried with the parameter SERVICE=WCS instead of SERVICE=WMS, to no avail.

Can QGIS server handle WCS?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if Qgis-server can handle WCS yet, so I advise you two great map-server applications: [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html) and [Geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/services/index.html)